# Set Interval NaN variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var remaining_time = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < my_shares.data.length; i++) {
            remaining_time[i] = my_shares.data[i].remainingTime;
            setInterval(function () {
                $datatable_my_shares.find('tbody > tr').each(function () {
                    remaining_time[i] -= 1;
                    $(this).find('td:last').html(moment.duration(parseInt(remaining_time[i]), "seconds").format("d ["+GENERAL.day+"] hh ["+GENERAL.hour+"] mm ["+GENERAL.minute+"] ss ["+GENERAL.second+"]", {trim: false}));
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
```

remaining_time array is defined in for loop but when the setInterval starts, it says remaining_time is NaN.

How can i use remaining_time array in setInterval...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `i` variable has iterated to the end before any of the `setInterval` callbacks has been called, so by the time they execute you point beyond the end of the array.

To solve this, declare `i` as a block scoped variable: that way every iteration of the loop will have its own instance of `i`, which is then also referenced from within the `setInterval` callback:

```
for (let i = 0; // ..etc
//   ^^^
```